# Crop Image using imagecopyresampled + Jcrop

Tags: php, image, crop, jcrop

I'm using Jcrop to crop images from the user. I followed the tutorial here: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Implementation_Theory.html. Here's my code

```
private function resizeImage($file_info)
{
    $dst_w        = $dst_h        = 150;
    $jpeg_quality = 90;

    $src                  = realpath($file_info['directory'] . '/' . $file_info['name']);

    // CHMOD before cropping
    chmod($src, 0777);

    switch (strtolower($file_info['mime'])) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($src);
            break;
        default:
            exit('Unsupported type: ' . $file_info['mime']);
    }
    $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);

    // Resize and crop the image
    imagecopyresampled(
        $dst_img, $src_img,                 // Destination and Source image link resource
        0, 0,                               // Coordinate of destination point
        $this->crop['x'], $this->crop['y'], // Coordinate of source point
        $dst_w, $dst_h,                     // Destination width and height
        $this->crop['w'], $this->crop['h']  // Source width and height
    );

    // Output the image
    switch (strtolower($file_info['mime'])) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            imagejpeg($dst_img, null, $jpeg_quality);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            imagepng($dst_img);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            imagegif($dst_img);
            break;
        default:
            exit('Unsupported type: ' . $file_info['mime']);
    }
}
```

I have checked both directory and file are writable (0777 permission). All variables I'm using are well-defined as well, nothing error. However, the final image is still in its original form, not cropped.

Anybody knows why it's not working? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you're using `list()` to get the width and height of the source image, but you're not using it in your `imagecopyresampled()` call. Everything else looks fine as far as i can see, if that doesn't fix it the problem is probably somewhere else in the class.

here's my cropping method for reference, if it helps.

```
    /**
     * Crops the image to the given dimensions, at the given starting point
     * defaults to the top left
     * @param type $width
     * @param type $height
     * @param type $x
     * @param type $y
     */
    public function crop($new_width, $new_height, $x = 0, $y = 0){
        $img = imagecrop($this->image, array(
            "x" => $x, 
            "y" => $y,
            "width" => $new_width,
            "height" => $new_height
        ));

        $this->height = $new_height;
        $this->width = $new_width;

        if(false !== $img) $this->image = $img;
        else self::Error("Could not crop image.");

        return $this;
    }
```

---

resizing method, for reference..

```
/**
 * resizes the image to the dimensions provided
 * @param type $width (of canvas)
 * @param type $height (of canvas)
 */
public function resize($width, $height){
    // Resize the image
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagealphablending($thumb, false);
    imagesavealpha($thumb, true);
    imagecopyresampled($thumb, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->width, $this->height);

    $this->image = $thumb;
    $this->width = $width;
    $this->height = $height;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Yup, I forget to delete the list() line hehe. Thanks for your ref to imagecrop, though not documented yet in PHP manual, I definitely will try it

Comment: Oh, does imagecrop do the resize too? Am using imagecopyresampled to crop and resize the image to 150x150

Comment: no crop won't resize, but i've added my resize method too, if it helps.